# Why does camel retain exchanges in inflightrepository?

Tags: java, service, apache-camel

My team has a working (very simple) service running through apache camel, functionally everything tests ok but load-testing shows that the service consumes memory over time. Digging into a the heap-dumps it turns out that the memory consumption is coming from the inflight-repository. It appears that every single exchange sent over the route is being retained but we can't identify any reason why an exchange should be retained once the route completes and the exchange is successfully delivered.

The initial (knee-jerk) reaction to the problem from my team is that it was a memory-leak but I don't believe this is the case - we just have an unexpected action - the exchanges are never de-referenced so garbage collection doesn't attempt to dispose of them.

The hard part is that it isn't just one copy of an exchange that appears to be retained it is every step of the exchange lifecycle that is retained, while the route isn't particularly complex it does implement a split-aggregate route that then exaggerates the problem.

We've considered adding a component to flush stale exchanges from the inflightrepository but that rather misses the point.

Can anyone explain why Camel is behaving like this?

Comment: No code? I dont see this behaviour on my routes.

Comment: Without providing the entire code for the service - a sizeable set of code in itself, it would be fairly pointless providing some snippets. That isn't the question though - what are the reasons for camel retaining inflight exchanges? Perhaps "when does camel remove an exchange from the inflightrepository?" would be a better question...

Comment: I have not seen this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

After considerable digging the solution turned out to be pretty trivial. The route generates custom a exchangeId to simplify the tracking of an exchange against requests made by clients. The result, at the end of the route, is that when an exchange is destroyed (removed from inflight repository) the key:value map of exchangeId:exchange in the repository doesn't contain the custom exchangeId and, for obvious reasons, does not remove the completed exchange.

This appears to be a side-effect of using an aggregate strategy. Without this the exchanges are removed as expected.

In short it was user error...

Comment: Not user error at all. Your answer helped me realize the problem, but the fact that Camel has an inflight repository indexed by the exchangeId, and that we can simply do `exchange.setId("mashedPotatoes")` and this does not automatically update said repository is the framework's fault, not ours. This behaviour should be encapsulated. We just had an application crash because of a memory leak due to this problem.